# UnicodeEncodeError AND TypeError: can only concatenate str (not “bytes”) to str

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, google-custom-search

I have a problem and it is that I try to search in results with Google Custom search api for python but when I search the things that are stored in a varibale instead of writting them manually it says UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa2' in position 104: ordinal not in range(128). When I solve it with

```
    .encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

it displays another error such as that the google custom search

```
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str.
```

PD: I have also tried some thing such as str() or .decode alone.

Edit: Sure, the input that is store in the variables come from Pytesseract that reads the text of an image. So, I store this information in a variable and then I tried to search this information in a google custom search API. As it displayed an Unicode error, I looked in stackoverflow the solution and I found that I could try to .decode the varible in order to not have this problem anymore. In fact this problem was solved but now another one appeared and it is the one of TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str. So, I can't use the .decode function because it will display anopther error. What can I do?

Edit 2.0

```
text_photo = pytesseract.image_to_string(img2) #this will read the text and put it in a variable
text_photo = text_photo.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '') #this will elimininate de /n


rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url_google_1 + text_photo1 + '+' + text_photo2 + url_google_2).read()
```

the url_google 1 containg the first part of the link (api key...) for a google search and the second contains what I want to get from google. In the middle I add the variable because it is what i want to search. If I write hello is works perfectly the problem is that the format that tesseract writes is not compatible I have tried to use str(text_photo) and the .decode but doesn't work json_data = json.loads(rawData)

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to understand all the details of your specific problem, but I'm quite sure the root cause is the following:

Python 3 distinguishes two string types, `str` and `bytes`, which are similar, yet incompatible.

Once you understand what this means, what each of them can/can't do, and how to go from one to the other, I'm sure you can figure out how to properly construct the URL for the API call.

Different types, incompatible:

```
>>> type('abc'), type(b'abc')
(<class 'str'>, <class 'bytes'>)

>>> 'abc' + b'abc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

>>> b'abc' + 'abc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

If you want to combine them, you need to convert everything to the same type.
For conversion, encode `str` to `bytes`, decode `bytes` to `str`:

```
>>> 'abc'.encode()
b'abc'
>>> b'abc'.decode()
'abc'
```

The `str.encode` and `bytes.decode` methods take an optional `encoding=` parameter, which defaults to UTF-8.
This parameter defines the mapping between the characters in a `str` and the octets in a `bytes` object.
If there's a problem mapping characters to bytes with the given encoding, you'll encounter a `UnicodeEncodeError`.
This happens if you use a character that isn't defined in the given mapping:

```
>>> '5 £'.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Similarly, if some text had been encoded with encoding X but you try to decode it with encoding Y, you might see a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
>>> b = '5 £'.encode('utf8')
>>> b
b'5 \xc2\xa3'
>>> b.decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can avoid the exception with the `errors="ignore"` strategy, but you will lose information this way:

```
>>> '5 £'.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
b'5 '
```

Typically, if you work with text, you use `str` everywhere.
You should also not often need to use `.encode/.decode` directly; often file handlers etc. accept `str` and will convert them to `bytes` behind the scene.

In your case, you need to find out where and why you have a mixture of `str` and `bytes`, then make sure everything has the same type before concatenating.